# I am trying to use wifite on kali linux windows subsystem

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airmon-ng

I am using modified wifite for linux:https://github.com/derv82/wifite2
But i can't get it to work.
I have instaled all necessary apps for wifite to work.
Every time when i run it it give out: "Error: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces"
I am using lastest version of windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Can you verify if there is a functioning wireless interface that the subsystem can use?

Comment: WSL (1, I heard there's a WSL2 coming) doesn't emulate ALL linux features in its system calls, especially when it's about non standard network usage. example: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1349

Comment: The solution is to boot Kali linux from an USB key with Kali installed. Or else maybe try from a VM (not WSL) with the wifi device in passthrough.

Answer (score 1):

Try using kali in a virtual box

In many cases the wireless adapters dont work properly on windows but they work well for linux and linux in virtual box

Make sure that wireless adapter is monitor mode compatable. If it is not you cant enable monitor mode on it.